# Correct use of async and await

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm just starting to deal with Asynchronous programming in c#, and I started reading about async methods and await.

In this block of code below, the WPF application takes an input from the user, saves it to a file in the Bin directory, and reads it back to the textbox. I had to use `async` methods to read and write, but I also need to implement `await` in the methods inside the `WriteText` and `ReadText` methods.

Can you give me a brief explanation on how I should implement the use of async and await in this code?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnWriteFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       await WriteFile();
    }

    private async void btnReadFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await ReadFile();
    }

    public async Task WriteFile()
    {
        string filePath = @"SampleFile.txt";
        string text = txtContents.Text;

        Task task1 = new Task( () =>  WriteTextAsync(filePath, text));
    }

    private async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
    {
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
              //sourceStream.BeginWrite(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
             await ?? sourceStream.BeginWrite(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length, null, null);
        };
    }

    public async Task ReadFile()
    {
        string filePath = @"SampleFile.txt";

        if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(filePath + " not found", "File Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string text = await ReadText(filePath);
                txtContents.Text = text;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
    {
         using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
            bufferSize: 4096))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                sb.Append(text);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Nick I think Code Review works better when you've working code that you have a question about, rather than when you've a programming question about a feature you don't quite get.

Comment: Thanks @JonHanna, you're absolutely right. I'll check your answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take them one at a time:

```
public async Task WriteFile()
{
  string filePath = @"SampleFile.txt";
  string text = txtContents.Text;
  Task task1 = new Task( () =>  WriteTextAsync(filePath, text));
}
```

What's task1 doing here? You need to actually have run it and await on it:

```
public async Task WriteFile()
{
  string filePath = @"SampleFile.txt";
  string text = txtContents.Text;
  Task task1 = new Task( () =>  await WriteTextAsync(filePath, text));
  await task1;
}
```

But wait! We're creating a `Task` that creates a `Task` and then waits on that `Task`. Why not just return the `Task` in the first place?

```
public Task WriteFile()
{
  string filePath = @"SampleFile.txt";
  string text = txtContents.Text;
  return WriteTextAsync(filePath, text);
}
```

Remember, `async` makes it easier for us to create methods that perform something in a  `Task`, but if you have already have a `Task` then it's a waste of time.

Also, as a matter of convention you should name your asynchronous methods to all end in `Async`. This is even more so here, because you differ from the other `WriteTextAsync` only in signature:

```
public Task WriteTextAsync()
{
  return WriteTextAsync(@"SampleFile.txt", txtContents.Text);
}
```

Really this is no different to how if you had a non-async `void WriteText(string filePath, string text)` you would call it from a non-async `void WriteText()`. Nothing actually new here.

Now, onto that more involved `WriteTextAsync`:

Because we've now got Tasks we don't need to use the old `BeginWrite` at all (but see below), we just use `WriteAsync` analogously to how we use `Write`:

```
private async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
  byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
  using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 
    bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
  {
    await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
  }
}
```

`ReadFile()` is fine. Let's look at what it calls into:

```
private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
{
  using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
    bufferSize: 4096))
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
      string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
      sb.Append(text);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

This will work, but it won't gain anything. However, we can replace the `Read` with `await`ing `ReadAsync`:

```
private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
{
  using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
    bufferSize: 4096))
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
      string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
      sb.Append(text);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

A better overall solution to the non-async version, simpler and more resilient in the face of encodings that might have characters split by such a `Read`, would have been to use `ReadToEnd()`. Likewise a better version here is to use `ReadToEndAsync()`:

```
private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
{
  using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
    bufferSize: 4096))
    {
    using(var rdr = new StreamReader(sourceStream, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
      return await rdr.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

Note that while we're returning the result of `await`ing a task, we cannot in this case just replace this with `return rdr.ReadToEndAsync()` because then we'll leave the `using` before the `ReadToEndAsync()` has actually finished. We need `await` to make sure we've got the actual result of that and then do the `IDisposable.Dispose()` calls that leaving a `using` invokes.

## Using TPL (async) with the old APM (`BeginXxx` … `EndXxx`):

Let's imagine we didn't have `stream.WriteAsync()` and had to use `stream.BeginWrite()` and `stream.EndWrite()`. Something like this can happen if you are using an older library.

We can use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to create a `Task` that wraps the old approach in the new. Hence:

```
private async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
  byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
  using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 
    bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
  {
    await Task.Factory.FromAsync(sourceStream.BeginWrite, sourceStream.EndWrite, encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length, null);
  }
}
```

And:

```
private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
{
  using(FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
    bufferSize:4096))
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    int numRead;
    while((numRead = await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(sourceStream.BeginRead, sourceStream.EndRead, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null)) != 0)
    {
      sb.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

This is a clearly a lot more convoluted than just having an `XxxAsync` method we can `await`, but it's still simpler than calling `BeginXxx` and then handling `EndXxx` in a callback, especially in cases like the `ReadText` above where this then has to lead to another loop into `BeginXxx`.

Comment: Thanks again Mr Jon, this is a majestic explanation that made me understand it better and have a clear concept about async methods which for me is very interesting. Teaching with real examples is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

The FileStream class has asynchronous methods for reading and writing to the stream: `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync`, so all you need to do is swap out those methods in your code, and prefix them with await:

```
private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
        bufferSize: 4096))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
        int numRead;
        while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
            sb.Append(text);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

and

```
private async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };
}
```

I'm sure these two methods can be simplified further, but this should get you started on the async methods.

And just so you're aware, if you were trying to use a class that didn't have async methods, and you wanted to perform that task on a separate thread, you could still make use of async/await in this fashion:

```
private async Task<string> ReadText(string filePath)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return File.ReadAllText("textfilepath.txt");
    });
}
```